# Magento 2 : Flush Cache Backend - Permission error

Tags: cache, magento2.4.6, magento-cache-management

I have a server with 2 magento 2 instances installed. Each one is owned by a different user. One instance works flawlessly, the other has a small issue :

when I try to flush the cache from backend I got the following error ( I encounter no errors when flushing from ssh running php bin/magento cache:clean and php bin/magento cache:flush ) as far as I know folders and files permissions are correct and ownership aswell (m2owner:www-data).

```
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): The file "/opt/m2/auth.json" is not readable.
<pre>#1 Composer\Factory::validateJsonSchema() called at [vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:338]
#2 Composer\Factory->createComposer() called at [vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:629]
#3 Composer\Factory::create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerFactory.php:45]
#4 Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php:368]
#5 Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getComposer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php:381]
#6 Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getLocker() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php:244]
#7 Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getSystemPackages() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php:120]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getSystemPackageVersion() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php:80]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion() called at [vendor/magento/module-admin-notification/Model/Feed.php:235]
#10 Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed->getFeedData() called at [vendor/magento/module-admin-notification/Model/Feed.php:164]
#11 Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed->checkUpdate() called at [vendor/magento/module-admin-notification/Observer/PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver.php:50]
#12 Magento\AdminNotification\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:88]
#13 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:74]
#14 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:65]
#15 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php:95]
#16 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:271]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatchPreDispatchEvents() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:211]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:146]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

any idea on how to get this to work from the back-end as it`s supposed to?

Comment: which magento version you use for both installation?

Comment: magento community 2.4.6

Comment: Have you try to run the cache clean and flush command? Does it working fine without and error from CLI? or same issue face there a well?

Comment: yes, from CLI it works without issues, it only gives the error when trying from backend